# Foreach backwards for listboxes?

Tags: c#

```
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.SelectedItems)
{ 
   lvi.index;
}
```

This foreaches for all selected items, but how do i do this backwards?

Like first index 3 then 2 then 1.

Thankyou!

Comment: are you familiar with the term called `Reverse` you can't just do a quick google search..? what have you tried ?

Comment: Im not sure how to reverse listView1.SelectedItems

Comment: This is not a duplicate, as SelectedItems does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`, only IEnumerable.

Comment: @MugMug if this helped correct your issue please mark it as the accetable answer thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in istView1.SelectedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().AsEnumerable().Reverse());
```

Comment: Why do you have to explicitly cast and call AsEnumerable()?

Comment: Yup .AsEnumerable() is not needed :)

Comment: because `SelectedItems does not implement generic IEnumerable<ListViewItem>`

Comment: And so the "closed as" duplicate is not exactly a duplicate.

Comment: @EricJ. notice how I am using the `Cast<T>` taken from reading the MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedlistviewitemcollection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yep I vaguely recalled the need for it when working with pre-generic collections but did not recall the details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use for to iterate over the available indexes

```
for (int i = (listView1.Items.Count - 1); i == 0; i--)
{
    // i is the index
}
```